# Outer constructor with fewer argument

Tags: types, constructor, julia

I want to do something like

```
struct Test
    nParticles::Int64
    particleIDs::Vector{Particle}
    function Test(nParticles::Int32)
        particleIDs = createPmarticles(nParticles)
        ...
    end
end
```

such that the variable `particleIDs` is defined inside the type with the help of the first argument `nParticles` and the function `createPmarticles` (which is defined somewhere else).

The question is this type of outer constructor is not allowed as far as I can see

> LoadError: LoadError: invalid redefinition of type Test

So, is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: There's probably no reason to have the length of the `particleIDs` as a separate field in your struct. Calling `length` on the array has O(1) complexity (it's free, basically) and is guaranteed to always be correct. Adding length as a separate field is redundant and a source of errors/bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
struct Test
    nParticles::Int64
    particleIDs::Vector{String}
    Test(nParticles::Int32) = new(nParticles, [string(i) for i in 1:nParticles])
end
```

And now some test:

```
julia> Test(Int32(3))
Test(3, ["1", "2", "3"])
```

Note that this has covered the default constructor so now when you write `Test(1,["nnn"])` you will get an error.
If you rather want to have an additional external constructor you can define it outside of `struct` such as (note that `struct Test2` is not using the `new` constructor):

```
struct Test2
    nParticles::Int64
    particleIDs::Vector{String}
end
Test2(nParticles::Int32) = Test2(nParticles, [string(i) for i in 1:nParticles])
```

Now this can be used:

```
julia> Test2(Int32(3))
Test2(3, ["1", "2", "3"])
```

But you can still do:

```
julia> Test2(1,["nnn"])
Test2(1, ["nnn"])
```